# Change filename for each new iteration of requests.get (file download to machine)

Tags: python-3.x, filenames

I'm using requests.get to download files from google searches, the search has a random input and runs every hour, so each file is different and is saved to my machine.
How can I write the below to increase the number by one in the file name ("testPDF1.pdf" in this example) for each run?

```
import requests

PDFurl = pdfGrab[0]
r = requests.get(PDFurl, allow_redirects=True)

open("testPDF1.pdf", "wb").write(r.content)
```

I've found similar questions that resolve with a basic `+` `str` stuff, and also advised to define encoding, I've tried this too -

```
PDFurl = pdfGrab[0]
r = requests.get(PDFurl, allow_redirects=True)

import io
for i in xrange(10):
   with io.open("testPDF_" + str(i) + ".pdf", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(str(func(i))

open("testPDF"+str(i)+".pdf", "wb").write(r.content)
"testPDF_%s.pdf" % i
"testPDF_{}.pdf".format(i)
```

But I get a syntax error -

```
open("testPDF"+str(i)+".pdf", "wb").write(r.content)
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is all getting a little bit over my head, any help appreciated.

Comment: You get a syntax error because you forgot a closing parenthesis in the line above, not because you changed the filename in each iteration.

Comment: In python 3, you can simply use range instead of xrange. You can also check if the file exists with `os.path.exists` to determine is a file already exists and then change file name accordingly.

Comment: So I added that (thanks) and now im getting an error with the func piece, I've tried to install dictutil to use it but none of my pip install attempts work (python3 -m pip, pip3 etc.). 
I can't find anything online about dictutil having changed but without it I cannot use func, any ideas?